# Assert.AreSame is not working for okObject result even when the objects are same

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have the following code for a Unit test.I'm using `Mock` library for unit testing.
Even when the objects are the same, the assert call fails.

```
  var service = new Mock<IRiskAssetProxyService>();
            var controller = new AssetProxyController(service.Object);
            List<AssetProxyWrapper> mockAssetProxyMappings = new List<AssetProxyWrapper>();
            AssetProxyWrapper awrapper1 = new AssetProxyWrapper
            {

                assetProxyMapping = new AssetProxyMapping
                {
                    AssetId = "testasset",
                    IsActive = true,
                    ProxyAssetId = "testproxy",
                    AssetIdType = "testtype",
                    testcode= "testcode",
                    ProxyAssetIdType = "testproxytype"
                },
                myCodes = new List<string> { "test"}
            };
            mockAssetProxyMappings.Add(awrapper1);

            OkObjectResult okResult = new OkObjectResult(mockAssetProxyMappings);            
            service.Setup(service => service.GetAllAssetProxyMapping()).Returns(mockAssetProxyMappings);

            var result = controller.GetAll() ;
     
            Assert.AreSame(okResult, result);
```

What i'm i doing wrong? Please advice.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Where should the Equals method be overridden ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal?view=visualstudiosdk-2022

Comment: btw @MakePeaceGreatAgain, aresame does not make equals check, it just checks references

 AreSame:

Tests whether the specified objects both refer to the same object and throws an exception if the two inputs do not refer to the same object.
AreEqual:

Tests whether the specified objects are equal and throws an exception if the two objects are not equal.

Comment: If your `result` you should use `CollectionAssert`

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer Aah, wasn't sure if your comment was ment to be adressed to me. Anyway that changes the question from a dupe to something unclear, as we have no clue why the two variables reference something different, unless OP does show the code for `GetAll`.

Comment: [`Assert.AreSame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aresame?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) checks the two objects are literally the same object (i.e the same reference). They cannot be the same given your controller has no reference to `okResult`. [`Assert.AreEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) won't work either, as `OkObjectResult` has reference equality. You'll likely need to check the properties individually.

Comment: @CharlesMager as far as i am concerned this should be the answer, and it should point out that when comparing individual props, AreEqual must be used, as AreSame will still break the test

Comment: @CharlesMager okay. Is there a way i can cast the ActionResult to the list of objects so that i can compare properties.